# C++ function prototype equivalent in javascript?

Tags: javascript

So I want to call function B in function A, but function B is fully declared after function A.  I know that in c++ we'd use function prototypes on B, but what about javascript?

code:

```
markerArray = function() {
    // some code here
    this.array = [];
    this.clearArray = function() {
        for(var i = 0; i<this.getLength(); i++)
            // for loop code
    }
    this.getLength = function() {
        return this.array.length;
    }
    // some code here
}
```

these reason why I put this.getLength below is mainly because my coding style/structure is more readable this way

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not a problem. Function declarations are hoisted to the top of the enclosing variable environment, so they do not  need to be declared in order.

```
A();

function A() {
    B();
}

function B() {
    alert('B was called');
}
```

If you meant something else, you'll need to explain it in your question.

Comment: cool, thought i had this error once, but i guess i was mistaken

Comment: @Derek: Be aware that function declarations as I've shown in my answer are different from anonymous functions that are part of some expression. So if you did `var A = function() { B(); }; var B = func...`, then the order would matter, unless you're not invoking them until later.

Comment: ah, is see, in fact, I did declare my function as part of an object such as this.A = function()..., this.B = function()..., how do you get around this?

Comment: @Derek: So this is happening within a constructor function? Could you post the code in your question?

Comment: @Derek: There's no issue in your code with the order of the functions. But are you using `markerArray` as a constructor by calling it with `new` to create a new object?

Comment: @Derek: Then I don't see any issue with your code. When you do `new markerArray();`, those functions will be created and assigned to the new object, which is referenced by `this`. What specific issue are you having? If you're not familiar with OOP in JavaScript, you may need to read up on how `this` works. It's kind of an odd topic in JS.

Answer (score 4):

Javascript doesn't care about this requirement.  It will simply work as long as Function A isn't called until after the file is loaded.  Function A will be defined, Function B will be defined, then Function A can be called using Function B inside of it with no problem.

Answer (score 0):

It depends on how you declare your functions.  If you declare a function via the Function constructor or a function expression, order matters.

```
a(1); //this call won't work
//function expression of an anonymous function assigned to the variable multiply
var a = function(i) {         
    b(i);
}
// b is defined using Function constructor
var b = new Function("i","alert('B was called with ' + i)");
a(1); //this call will work
```